# How to check if a cell contains value

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

I have a code that checks the position (which cell) of a given cell value. How can I check for every cell that is under this cell for 4 rows long (so in new rows) if that cell contains any value (so its not null)? I started it but I have no idea how to continue it.

```
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        if thecell.value == "Table1":
```

Comment: Condition {if thecell.value} will evaluate to True if value is not None or 0.
You have a data example?

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate()` may be helpful.

Example:

```
for y, row in enumerate(range(rows)):
    for x, col in enumerate(range(cols)):
        #making this a 2d array for the example
        if thecell[y][x] == "Table1":
            for i in range(y + 1, y + 4):
                if not thecell[i][x] == None:
                    #Do whatever you need to do when the cell is NOT none
                    print("CELL EMPTY AT:  " + str(x) + "," + str(y))
```

Disclaimer:  I know nothing about xlrd. If you supply me more of your code I can probably help more, though. Like where are you getting rows/ranges? Stuff like that. There may even be a built in method to check whether or not a cell is blank (because there is in excel, it's `ISBLANK()`).

This code will certainly not work if you copy and paste it, but it should at least give you an idea or two of how to solve your problem. Let me know if this solution works or if you need more help on it.